# Best way for Order Array by Keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to push new value in array, and that this value was automatically ordered.
I try to explain me:

I have an array like this:

```
arr[0.1] = Mark
arr[0.3] = Sonia
arr[0.5] = John
```

This array is filled automatically, and I'm receiving a lot of new data for add and for modify the name (value).

If I receive 0.1->Sonia, I change the value of 0.1, arr[0.1] = Sonia. But if I receive a new position, like 0.2, I need push this value between 0.1 and 0.3 positions, not in the final of array.

This is posible, or I only can sort the array after add any value?
I'm using es6, I thought I saw new format of array, that can used like list.

**EDIT**

Not is necessarly use an array. I only need can order this values automatically, because they are update constantly.

**EDIT2**

I think that here are two solutions, but I don't know how are the best.

**Solution 1**:

Using an object for any key->value, add this into an array, and sort array any time that add new object. (Like Your answers) 
The problem here, is if the array content 1000 elements, and any second was added 10 new elements, I need to sort big array 10 times/s. 
And if a value name are modified also I need loop the array of objects for found the value.

**Solution 2**

Using array, like my example. When I receive a object, execute a loop for any element of array, and if the key value of array is < that the new value continue, until the second value are higher.
Pseudo code:

```
     var ObjReceived = {value:"0.125", name:"MARK"}  var arr = [];

     for arr.length
         if(arr-key < ObjReceived.value){
         continue    }else{
         arr[ObjReceived.value] = ObjReceived.name  
  }
```

With this code, I only need loop array, until the position is correct. And if the name are modified, I don't need loop anything.

What do you thing?

Comment: Why are you using `0.1` and not `1` for the index ?

Comment: Just do `arr['0.2'] = value`? You do not need to use push, or I misunderstood the question

Comment: Because I need save this data, 0.1 is an example, is posible I get 0.002 or 0.588...

Comment: In JS arrays can only have **integer** indices (keys). No float values like `0.1` allowed

Comment: If you don't use integer indexes, you are not using it as an array. You simply assign properties, like to a regular object. It's the same as doing `arr.'0.1' = 'Mark'`. You will see the array itself is empty.

Comment: Ok, sorry for use a push term.. @nicovank, I can add element like: arr[0.2] = xxx

Comment: @hindmost, not are a float, are a String. I don't need necessarily use an array. What is the best way for that?

Comment: Use an object which have `"0.1"` , `"0.2"` , ... properties

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained why/how you get such strange keys like 0.588 etc. and what you want to do with the saved values in the end.

Comment: @weedoze, ok, I can use an object like obj{k:0.1, name:Mark}. But how I can order automaticali all the values?

Comment: A binary search tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one.
It will loop through original array, compare the value then put in correct position.

```js
var array = [
              {value: 0.1, name: 'Mark'}, 
              {value: 0.3, name: 'Sonia'}
            ],
    new1 = {value: 0.2, name: 'John'},
    new2 = {value: 0.89, name: 'John1'},
    new3 = {value: 0.77, name: 'John2'};

console.log('original',array);

function pushSort(obj) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (obj['value'] > array[i]['value'])
      continue;
    break;
  }
  //using splice to insert new element on specific position
  return array.splice(i,0,obj);  
}
pushSort(new1);
console.log('add', new1, array);

pushSort(new2);
console.log('add', new2, array);

pushSort(new3);
console.log('add', new3, array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an array of objects with the numerical value and the name as properties

```
[
    {
        value: 0.1,
        name: 'Mark'
    },
    {
        value: 0.3,
        name: 'Sonia'
    }
]
```

After each insert sort with

```
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
});
```

for ascending order.

Working example:

```js
var array = [{ value: 0.1, name: 'Mark' }, { value: 0.3, name: 'Sonia' }];

console.log(array);
array.push({ value: 0.2, name: 'John' });
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
});
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For getting just the top 10 values, you might use an additional array which has only the top values and for every new item from the server you might check if the numerical value is smaller than the top 10 value and insert it into the top 10 array as well. Then sort only top 10 and limit to 10 items. Proceed.

Comment: I already thought of this, but the problem is thar the values are added contantly, 10/s +-, And I try not to update the array sorting they values. The array can content 1000 vlaues.

Comment: where do you get the numerical values from?

Comment: I get the info from a server. I receive any second objects like your example ({value:xxx,name:xxx}). I try to not sort the array with 1000 values, 10 times any second.

Comment: what happens after you recieve new data? what do you do with it?

Comment: what do you do with the data? that is the main question, and not how to store the data and sort. pleas answer the purpose of the ordered data and why it does not go in between of the interval of getting new data ...

Comment: The finally is that the array are ordened all the time. If I need the firsts 10 values, I can easely get that. If I need values between 30-50, get this values ordenered. I need make this a lot of times, any minute

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "mark",
  "value": 0.1
}, {
  "name": "Sonia",
  "value": 0.3
}, {
  "name": "John",
  "value": 0.5
}];

function compare(a, b) {
  return a.value - b.value;
}

data.push({
  "name": "Jason",
  "value": 0.2
});
console.log("BEFORE");
console.log(data);

data.sort(compare);

console.log("AFTER");
console.log(data);
```

Comment: I already thought of this, but the problem is thar the values are added contantly, 10/s +-, And I try not to update the array sorting they values. The array can content 1000 vlaues.

Answer (score 0):

**If...**

- the keys are always in the format of `0.###` (I don't know where these are coming from) AND
- the array needs to be sorted at ALL times,

you could do:

```
var arr = new Array(1000);
var obj = {
    k: '0.588',
    name: 'Mark'
};
arr[obj.k * 1000] = obj.name;
```

Of course, the array would have many empty positions.

**Else...**

I would recommend one of the other suggested solutions. It depends on WHAT you want to do with the data. You could sort it as soon as you need to access it, otherwise there is not benefit of keeping it sorted ALL the time.